# Color-blind preview export

Tags: color

There are many ways to preview a map as it is seen by people with color vision impairment. ColorOracle, preview mode in QGIS, etc.
But none of these options allow exporting the modified image, only printscreen and save.
How can I transform map into color vision impairment sight?

Comment: What about Visolve ? You will need to set to different colors like for example if you have two different greens one dark one light  then it is a no no... You wil need to change like blue, red, black so they don't look similar colors. I don't think there is a way to export or printscreen for that...

Comment: Related and still relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/accounting-for-colour-blindness-when-designing-maps

Comment: I would suggest putting this forward as a QGIS feature request - perhaps a button on the "Export Map to Image" dialog to "Save as Preview"?