# Examples of GIS Visualisation

Tags: visualisation

**Examples of GIS Visualisation**

Example:
Dr. John Snow (1813-1858), a legendary figure in the history of public health, epidemiology and anesthesiology created one of the first uses of geographical analysis on a static map to solve a problem of stopping the spread of cholera through Soho, London, England.

[image]

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Snow-cholera-map-1.jpg/643px-Snow-cholera-map-1.jpg

The first two cholera cases in 1848 occurred in the same room but a week apart at No. 8, New Lane (in red) near Gainsford Street in the community of Horsleydown... water pumps were causing the spread and over a period of time it was found after collating deaths and visualising them.

**Good Examples can be ancient, historical or cutting edge.**

[image]

source:
http://www.ph.ucla.edu/epi/snow/1859map/snowindex.html

Comment: Could you make the question more precise?  Are you asking for people to name, list, display, comment on, link to, ... visualization examples?  In what sense should they be "good"?  Must a "visualization" be map-like or can it be a more abstract representation of data?  The two examples you provide are interesting because the first one is awful, cartographically, but has been considered an effective use of mapping for solving an important problem, whereas the second appears to be of a purely cartographic nature.  It is unclear in what sense it is considered "good."

Comment: anything goes - along the lines of Examples of Beautiful Maps http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps

Comment: @Mapperz How, then, is this question not an exact duplicate of the one you reference?  Consider, too, that "anything goes" is so broad that it effectively ends the usefulness of such a thread.  Perhaps you can narrow its scope?

Comment: As you mention GIS Visualization is not "beautiful" consider the first map is not cartographically aesthetic but is a good geospatial visualisation to solve a specific problem.

Comment: I think 'thematic' questions are way to go here, for example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408/what-is-the-best-practice-for-visualisation-of-a-spatio-temporal-data-set , http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408/what-is-the-best-practice-for-visualisation-of-a-spatio-temporal-data-set , http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/best-practices-for-visualizing-speed, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/gis-and-natural-disasters-examples-of-geo-visualizations-and-geospatial-analysi . Asking for examples of geo-vis only might be tad too broad (?).

Comment: Im still not too sure what ur asking for.  Needs to be more specific in my opinion.  Not sure what im voting for.